# How to update values in a table from another table MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, inner-join

I created table_1 with a list of products and columns for price and quantity (both are currently `NULL` as a default for an empty value)
I have another table (table_2) with the same columns with info about price and quantity for each product.

How do I update table_1 with info from table_2?
I've tried to use subqueries with both `UPDATE` and `INSERT INTO` commands - Both didn't work.

I pasted the two tables here:
https://justpaste.it/8qusd

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please add the SQL statements that you tried and that did not work and explain in which way they did not work? Also, please add the tables to your post instead of pasting links to an image (see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for details).

Comment: THANKS! I've been using this platform for quite a while now, great community you've got here :) 


Unfortunately I have already deleted my previous attempts... RE the images - I wanted at first to do just this, but SO told me I have to reach minimum rating in order to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the update/join syntax:

```
update table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id
set t1.price = t2.price, t1.quantity = t2.quantity
```

Comment: This is what I got:

Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column.  To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.

Comment: @David: you have MySQL safe-update mode enabled. You can disable it for the current session with `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;`.

Comment: Hmmmmmm interesting......

But what does this safe-updated mode means? Do I want to keep it? Is it something like "idiot-proof" thing?

Comment: @David: see the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_safe-updates. Yes it's some kind of "idot-proof" security indeed. Not needed in my opinion.